# redeploy on fly war in EAR with multiples war (wildfly)

Tags: war, ear, wildfly-9, redeploy

It is possible to have several war in one EAR.

But is it possible to replace only one war in the EAR while deploying on admin console for example ?

example :

EAR
 WAR1
 WAR2

then i have to redeploy only WAR1 not entirely EAR

Comment: on console or via wifldy-maven-plugin it is not possible

Answer (score 0):

No, you'd need to redeploy the entire EAR. If it's just an EAR with several WAR's then you could just deploy each WAR separately.

However you may be able to use a [deployment overlay](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Deployment+Overlays?_sscc=t).

Comment: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/272630, in theory it is possible, in practice there is a bug